# Cypress test case gets stuck on the step where a file downloaded externally and waits for page to open

Tags: javascript, testing, download, automated-tests

I wrote a simple test case where on clicking Export option(dropdown), a file gets downloaded on background. However Cypress test halts on this step while going into a continuous waiting state. After some time it shows error that its timed out and expected page is not loaded.It gives error on the commands proceeding it.I have used cy.wait() and timeout parameter in click function where i am clicking the link that triggers the action to export file but no luck and I am unable to figure out whats happening here.

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('Test the export customers list functionality', () => {
before("LoginFunction", function(){
cy.LoginFunction().wait(1000)
});    

it('Export customers list' ,() =>{
cy.contains('.sidebar li', 'CustomersListingPage').then((specificElement) => {
if (specificElement.length > 0) {
cy.wrap(specificElement).find('a').click();
cy.wait(2000);  

//Export
cy.get('a').filter('.dropdown-toggle').eq(1).click({force: true});
cy.get('.export_file_link').click({force: true});
cy.log();
}
});
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code provided, it seems like the test case is getting stuck while waiting for the file to be downloaded and the page to open. Cypress commands like `cy.wait()` and `cy.get().click()` are not suitable for handling file downloads as they are designed to work with the DOM and cannot interact with files downloaded externally.

To handle file downloads in Cypress, you can use the `cy.request()` command to intercept the download request and save the file using `cy.writeFile()`. Here's how you can modify your test case to handle file downloads:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('Test the export customers list functionality', () => {
  before("LoginFunction", function(){
    cy.LoginFunction().wait(1000);
  });    

  it('Export customers list' ,() =>{
    cy.contains('.sidebar li', 'CustomersListingPage').then((specificElement) => {
      if (specificElement.length > 0) {
        cy.wrap(specificElement).find('a').click();
        cy.wait(2000);  

        // Intercept the download request
        cy.intercept('GET', '/your_export_endpoint').as('downloadFile');

        // Trigger the export action
        cy.get('a').filter('.dropdown-toggle').eq(1).click({force: true});
        cy.get('.export_file_link').click({force: true});

        // Wait for the download to complete
        cy.wait('@downloadFile').then((interception) => {
          // Get the downloaded file data from the interception
          const fileContent = interception.response.body;
          
          // Use cy.writeFile() to save the file
          cy.writeFile('path/to/save/yourFile.csv', fileContent, 'binary');
        });

        cy.log('File downloaded successfully');
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

Make sure to replace `'your_export_endpoint'` with the actual endpoint that triggers the file download. Also, adjust the file path in `cy.writeFile()` according to your needs.

By intercepting the download request and saving the file, this approach allows you to handle file downloads in Cypress and proceed with the test after the download is complete.